# Can R paste() output "\"?

Tags: r, text

As stated in the [Intro to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf) manual,

```
paste("\\")
```

prints

```
[1] "\\"
```

Is it possible for paste to print out

```
[1] "\"
```

?

**update:** I didn't want Gavin's this nice answer to get stuck in the comments below, so I'll paste it here:

```
print(xtable(as.matrix("\\citep{citation}")), sanitize.text.function = function(x) {x})
```

Comment: What is your real question?  Would `file.path()` help?

Comment: Do you want `print()` -ed output or would something like `cat()` or `writeLines()` do?

Comment: @Dirk I am trying to create a vector from a vector of bibtex citations that returns "\citep{citation}" from "citation", like paste("\citep{", citation, "}", sep='') @Gavin, presumably cat() would work, but I was using paste() since it returns a vector instead of a string from a vector; I could use an apply statement though

Comment: @David: no, what I mean't was, does it actually matter if the printed output contains `"\\"`. If you cat this out, it will contain only a single `\`. Are you doing this in any particular context? A Sweave file??

Comment: @Gavin - yes, I am using this to add citatons to a data frame that will become a table column via xtable in a Sweave file.

Comment: @David, then see my answer. IIRC you'll need to have ` \\ ` in there for xtable. Just ignore how R *prints* the vector in the console, xtable will spit it out via `cat()` or similar and the second ` \ ` will miraculously disappear.

Comment: @Gavin xtable(as.matrix("\\citep{citation}")) returns $\backslash$citep\{citation\} in the cell where I want \citep{citation}

Comment: @David: read the help for `print.xtable`, you are getting hit by the print method sanitizing the text to remove important LaTeX characters. The Xtable Gallery vignette has examples of how to handle sanitization, such as this: `print(xtable(as.matrix("\\citep{citation}")), sanitize.text.function = function(x) {x})`

Comment: @Gavin thanks for pointing that out - I would have been completely lost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the printed *representation* of a single "\" in R. Clearly the right answer will depend on your end usage, but will something like this do:

```
> citations <- paste("title", 1:3, sep = "")
> cites <- paste("\\citep{", citations, "}", sep = "")
> writeLines(cites)
\citep{title1}
\citep{title2}
\citep{title3}
```

Using `writeLines()` you can output that to a file using something like:

```
> writeLines(cites, con = file("cites.txt"))
```

Resulting in the following file:

```
$ cat cites.txt 
\citep{title1}
\citep{title2}
\citep{title3}
```

Answer (score 6):

You are confusing how something is stored and how it "prints".

You can use paste to combine a \ with something else, but if you print it then the printed representation will have \ to escape the \, but if you output it to a file or the screen using cat instead, then you get the single \, for example:

```
> tmp <- paste( "\\", "cite{", sep="" )
> print(tmp)
[1] "\\cite{"
> cat(tmp, "\n")
\cite{
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do is is to use the `write` command, e.g.

```
> write("\\", file="")
\
```

Write is usually used to write to files, so you need to set `file=""` to get it to print to STDOUT.

The \ is repeated in the write command so that it doesn't escape the closing quotation mark.

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it, but it works for me.

Edit: Realised slightly too late that you were using the paste() command. Hopefully my answer still bears some relevance to your plight. Apologies.