# How to gsub('%', '\%', ... in R?

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I want to export a latex table with a units column that has the percent (%) symbol.

```
library(xtable) 
foo <- data.frame(units='%', citation = '\\citep{authorYYYYabc}')
print(xtable(foo), sanitize.text.function = function(x) {x})
```

*note: above code has been changed since Joris' answer.*

In this case, the '%' is interpreted as a comment by LaTeX.

I have tried

```
gsub('%', '\\%', foo)
```

returns

```
[1] "1"
```

how can I convert the % to \% so that LaTex comments it out?

This question is a little bit like a previous question "[can R paste('\')?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4379681/199217); even polishing the same table, but I can't figure out this particular case.

Comment: My version of R (2.10.1 with xtable 1.5-6) appears to correctly escape the "%" in the output.

Comment: Same for me with R version 2.12.1   xtable 1.5-6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining Joris' answer with the codes in the comment:

```
library(xtable)
foo <- data.frame(units='%', citation = '\\citep{authorYYYYabc}')
print(xtable(foo), sanitize.text.function = function(x)gsub('%', '\\\\%', x))
```

Comment: Note `stresc` in the seqinr package.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand you completely correctly. If I do xtable(foo), then the % is correctly escaped :

```
...
  \hline
1 & \% \\ 
   \hline
...
```

If you want to make an escape slash for something else, you need a quadruple one in gsub :

```
> x <- gsub('%', '\\\\%', foo[,1])
> x
[1] "\\%"
> cat(x,"\n")
\%
```

Mind you, you cannot gsub in a dataframe, only in a vector. This can be shown by

```
> as.character(foo)
[1] "1"
```

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake in my original question should I ask it again or make corrections above - I am using `print(xtable(foo), sanitize.text.function function(x) {x})` to properly convert citations in the dataframe: `foo <- data.frame(units='%', citation = '\\citep{authorYYYYabc}')`

Comment: I apologize for changing the question and then selecting an answer to my revised question. I do appreciate the help.

Comment: @David: no prob. But you should have found the answer of Sacha by yourself. Read also `?grep` and `?regex` to learn about regular expressions in R. You won't regret it.